# In SWI prolog. Why my path is output two time, and how can I make shortest path?

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

```
ringing(5).
ringing(9).
ringing(16).

touching(2, 1).
touching(7, 1).
touching(1, 2).
touching(8, 2).
touching(8, 3).
touching(8, 4).
touching(9, 4).
touching(6, 5).
touching(9, 5).
touching(5, 6).
touching(9, 6).
touching(1, 7).
touching(8, 7).
touching(9, 7).
touching(10, 7).
touching(11, 7).
touching(12, 7).
touching(13, 7).
touching(14, 7).
touching(2, 8).
touching(3, 8).
touching(4, 8).
touching(7, 8).
touching(4, 9).
touching(5, 9).
touching(6, 9).
touching(7, 9).
touching(7, 10).
touching(7, 11).
touching(7, 12).
touching(7, 13).
touching(7, 14).
touching(15, 14).
touching(14, 15).
touching(16, 15).
touching(15, 16).

adjacent(RoomA, RoomB) :-
      touching(RoomA, RoomB)
   ;  touching(RoomB, RoomA).

path_to_phone(FirstRoom, LastRoom,Path) :- % Base Case
    ringing(LastRoom),
        %touching(FirstRoom, X),
        travel(FirstRoom, LastRoom, [FirstRoom],Q),
        reverse(Q,Path).

travel(FirstRoom, LastRoom,P, [LastRoom|P]) :-
%   write('who call this\n'),
    adjacent(FirstRoom,LastRoom).
travel(FirstRoom,LastRoom, Visited,Path) :-
    touching(FirstRoom,X),
    X \== LastRoom,
    \+member(X,Visited),
    %write(visited),
    travel(X,LastRoom,[X|Visited],Path).
    %write('call?\n').
```

In the path_to_phone, if one room with ring, then it will keep looking the path to that room.
I am not sure why the path is output two times. And Base on this, how can I make the shortest path to get the room.

Comment: adjacent(RoomA, RoomB) :- touching(RoomA, RoomB); touching(RoomB, RoomA).

path_to_phone(FirstRoom, LastRoom,Path) :- % Base Case
 ringing(LastRoom),
        %touching(FirstRoom, X),
        travel(FirstRoom, LastRoom, [FirstRoom],Q),
        reverse(Q,Path).

travel(FirstRoom, LastRoom,P, [LastRoom|P]) :-
% write('who call this\n'),
 adjacent(FirstRoom,LastRoom).

travel(FirstRoom,LastRoom, Visited,Path) :-
    touching(FirstRoom,X),
    X \== LastRoom,
    \+member(X,Visited),
    %write(visited),
    travel(X,LastRoom,[X|Visited],Path).
    %write('call?\n').

Comment: You can use the `!` operator at the end of your desired situation check to say "stop looking for other solutions", otherwise Prolog will automatically go back to the last point where it has multiple possible answers and try for those too.

Comment: As @TakuKoyahata has aptly answered, you meet double results because the answers satisfy your conditions in two ways. In Prolog you need to find a way to define success cases uniquely, which his answer covers for your particular problem. Do not be tempted to use a cut (`!`) to resolve this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you define bidirectional graphs in two ways.
you need only one way.
I mean you define "touching(2, 1)." and "touching(1,2)." and
adjacent/2 too.

These definitions are both for representing bidirectional graphs.
Either of two is required but both is redundant.

after deleting redundant terms like below, your code will work collectly.
(travel/2 also needs modification like below).

sorry for my bad English.

```
ringing(5).
ringing(9).
ringing(16).

touching(2, 1).
touching(7, 1).
%touching(1, 2).
touching(8, 2).
touching(8, 3).
touching(8, 4).
touching(9, 4).
touching(6, 5).
touching(9, 5).
%touching(5, 6).
touching(9, 6).
%touching(1, 7).
touching(8, 7).
touching(9, 7).
touching(10, 7).
touching(11, 7).
touching(12, 7).
touching(13, 7).
touching(14, 7).
%touching(2, 8).
%touching(3, 8).
%touching(4, 8).
%touching(7, 8).
%touching(4, 9).
%touching(5, 9).
%touching(6, 9).
%touching(7, 9).
%touching(7, 10).
%touching(7, 11).
%touching(7, 12).
%touching(7, 13).
%touching(7, 14).
touching(15, 14).
%touching(14, 15).
touching(16, 15).
%touching(15, 16).

adjacent(RoomA, RoomB) :-
      touching(RoomA, RoomB)
   ;  touching(RoomB, RoomA).

path_to_phone(FirstRoom, LastRoom,Path) :- % Base Case
    ringing(LastRoom),
        %touching(FirstRoom, X),
        travel(FirstRoom, LastRoom, [FirstRoom],Q),
        reverse(Q,Path).

travel(FirstRoom, LastRoom,P, [LastRoom|P]) :-
%   write('who call this\n'),
    adjacent(FirstRoom,LastRoom).
travel(FirstRoom,LastRoom, Visited,Path) :-
    adjacent(FirstRoom,X), %touching(FirstRoom,X),
    X \== LastRoom,
    \+member(X,Visited),
    %write(visited),
    travel(X,LastRoom,[X|Visited],Path).
    %write('call?\n').
```

```
    [trace]  ?- path_to_phone(2,5,A).
    A = [2, 1, 7, 8, 4, 9, 5] ;
    A = [2, 1, 7, 8, 4, 9, 6, 5] ;
    A = [2, 1, 7, 9, 5] ;
    A = [2, 1, 7, 9, 6, 5] ;
    A = [2, 8, 4, 9, 5] ;
    A = [2, 8, 4, 9, 6, 5] ;
    A = [2, 8, 7, 9, 5] ;
    A = [2, 8, 7, 9, 6, 5] ;
    false.
```

and to get shortest path , in this case you can use `findall`,`length` and `sort`  to get answer because the problem size is very little.
when nodes number is big, you can use `breadth first search` algorithm to get shortest path. It's required implementing `queue` data structure.